# Array Syntax Confusion in C

Tags: c, arrays, syntax, cs50

I'm trying to teach myself C via the iTunes University/Harvard CS50 course. In it a program is to be written which resizes a bitmap image file. To do this, I've defined an array (buffer) and written the necessary code for the program to work - it does work. However, I had to cheat and Google an answer as I couldn't figure it out, and I don't understand a particular piece of syntax in the solution and am hoping someone can help.

The block of code looks like the below and I've put in the comments my specific point of confusion:

```
// allocate array to hold scanline pixels - this is the array I define
RGBTRIPLE *buffer = malloc(bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));

// declare variable to track position in buffer array
int count;

// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, height = abs(oldHeight); i < height; i++)
{
    // initialize count var to 0
    count = 0;

    // iterate over pixels in scanline
    for (int j = 0; j < oldWidth; j++)
    {
        // temporary storage
        RGBTRIPLE triple;

        // read RGB triple from infile
        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

        // place pixel in buffer array n times
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            // below is the confusion. Some sudo code would be great!
            *(buffer+(count)) = triple;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this Harvard course titled "Programming Paradigms"? Or am I confusing it with a Stanford video course? If this is the one where a guy in a blue shirt is talking and drawing to a big blackboard, hit "stop" quickly, he says a lot of nonsense/wrong assumptions/bad practices.

Comment: BTW, it's not "sudo code". "Sudo code" would be the source code of the Unix root privilege utility called `sudo`. The word you are looking for is "pseudo code".

Comment: @H2CO3; I wanna listen that guy. Seriously! o.O

Comment: @haccks See my comments (and the incoming ignorant responses) on [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTSvthW34GU). Armed with a fresh copy of the C99 Standard, any intermediately experienced C programmer can point out **literally dozens of errors** in the presentation of this guy.

Comment: @H2CO3, I agree, just glanced into that video and this is incredibly fuzzy, imprecise, misleading, wrong ... but almost never correct.

Comment: @JensGustedt (And the "best" part is the guy who replied to my comment, asserting that "the professor has more experience than you will **ever have**" - an incredibly annoying argumentum ad hominem.)

Comment: @H2CO3 That would likely be a true statement (or at least it is from what I've seen) if the qualifier ".. at being simultaneously incorrect, ignorant, and lazy." was an addendum to his claim. I'm sure he's got you beat hands down on that regard.  =P

Comment: @WhozCraig :D :D :D so true. Well, I have nothing personal against that teacher. But it's sad that a lecturer at a top technical university such as Stanford makes serious mistakes (because, you know, beginners often believe that the teacher is 100% right; authority is just **too strong** a factor. As you can have perceived reading those comments. :-( )

Comment: It's the "This Is CS50" (Intro to Computer Science) course. Given by David Malan.

Comment: Thanks for note on pseudo v sudo. Must bee the Chili whether messing with my English...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the variable `buffer` is not an array variable. It is a pointer variable. Remember that **arrays are not pointers**.
Now the line

```
 *(buffer+(count)) = triple;
```

is using pointer arithmetic. `buffer` is a pointer to the `RGBTRIPLE` type and after allocating space to it, it is pointing to the first block of that memory. Adding the value of `count` to it increments it to the next block, i.e, giving the address of the next block. Dereferencing this address with `*` operator gives the value stored at that address. It can also be written as

```
buffer[count] = triple;
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. Just knowing it's called "pointer arithmetic" helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that writing `x[i]` is equal to writing `*(x+i)`, that is, sum i to the pointer x and read (or write) the value at that address.  So

```
*(buffer+(count)) = triple;
```

Is equal to:

```
buffer[count] = triple;
```

Remember also that when you add an integer to a pointer, as in `buffer+(count)`, you are incrementing the pointer by `count*sizeof(element_of_buffer)`. If you are incrementing a char pointer, this will add 1 to the pointer, if you do the same to an integer pointer in a 32bit machine, this will add 4 to the pointer (4 bytes, the size of an integer). This is transparent to you, and beacuse of that the pointer will always refer to a valid memory location, that is a multiple of the size of each element.

Comment: Thank you. That explanation is awesome and really helps wrap my head around it. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the part you don't understand is this bit: `*(buffer+(count))`

There are a couple of things to remember, the first being that `buffer` is not actually an array, it's a pointer to some memory. However, pointers can be indexed as arrays, and as arrays decays to pointer you can use an array as a pointer.

As for the syntax here, `*(buffer + count)` is the same as `buffer[count]`.

Trivia time: Due to the commutative nature of addition, `*(buffer + count)` can also be written as `*(count + buffer)`, which leads to `count[buffer]` being a valid expression. (And yes, this "backward" way of indexing exists in real code.)

Comment: Thank you for your help! You did a great job of explaining it.